# Am I posting to Facebook correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

Anyone use the [Koala gem](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) to post on a Facebook wall before? I am able to post fine (with the picture displayed), but can't seem to have the "share" link on the actual wall post. "Like" and "Comment" appear though.

I have the following:

```
        client = Koala::Facebook::API.new(user.token)

        options = { 
          :message     => "Message here",
          :description => "Description here",
          :link        => "http://#{APP_CONFIG['host']}/foobars/1", 
          :picture     => "#{photo.url}" 
        }
        client.put_object(user.facebook_uid, 'feed', options)
```

Am I missing something in `options`? Would anyone like to share their experience?

Comment: Your first stop should always be the docs/wiki/etc. of the gem itself - there's an issue there describing this exact problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to work by changing `feed` to `links`:

```
client.put_object(user.facebook_uid, 'links', options)
```